# Reverse colors for e-book reading

Tags: linux, colors, ebook

I want to read ebook, but its hard, when background is white and font is black. I want to change it, so how can I reverse colors on the screen? Is there any program for linux? Probably beryl can do it, but i need something lighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm using **[CoolReader](http://coolreader.org/e-index.htm)** 2 for Windows, it allows to adjust the fonts and colour scheme to you likings.

now version 3 has gone open source and cross-platform. certain features (such as TTS and skinning) are not available in version 3, but have a look at it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, Ctrl-Option-Command-8 will invert screen colors.